# SSO is not working between WebForms App and SPA of Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a B2C application registered in Azure AD B2C tenant. I have one root site (app) and two sub sites (apps). All the sites have been configured with same B2C Application and same Policy. SSO is not working between root site and sub-sites.

Main difference (between Root Site and Sub sites) is root-site built on Web Forms application and Sub-sites are built of SPA. Sub-sites generally have to be launched from root-site and it has got their own integration using MSAL.js

I understand that Web Form application uses Cookie as storage for authentication tokens where as SPA is storing auth tokens in local/session storage.

I want to know whether SSO supported between different types of applications in Azure AD B2C.

Comment: SSO Configuration has been done based on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso)

Comment: direct link... [Single sign-on (SSO) configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso#single-sign-on-sso-configuration)

Comment: If SSO config was the answer you should update the answer as such :)  You can answer your own question.